# "brctl evict" and "brctl download" incompatible with Box?

Tags: macos, box-api, icloud-drive

The "Download Now" and "Remove Download" contextual menu items built into OSX's Finder is normally an iCloud function that allows users to download or "un" download synced iCloud files in the Finder.

When Box is installed on the user's machine, these menu commands operate the same way. I was hoping I could find terminal commands that can achieve this from the command line, and I found these commands:

```
brctl download [FilePathHere]
brctl evict [FilePathHere]
```

However, they fail when the folder is a Box shared folder:

```
brctl: Unable to evict item at path '[FilePathHere]': 
    Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=6 "Path is 
    outside of any CloudDocs app library, will never sync" 
    UserInfo={NSDescription=Path is outside of any CloudDocs 
    app library, will never sync, NSFilePath=[FilePathHere]}
```

Do I need to install the Box CLI in order to control these functions in a different way? Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that `fileproviderctl` works well here. The [File Provider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider?language=objc) seems to be used by 3rd party cloud resources such as box.

To download: `fileproviderctl materialize [FilePathHere]`

To evict: `fileproviderctl evict [FilePathHere]`